# MediaWiki - Bootstrap Skin Not Rendering

Tags: mediawiki

I have a fresh install of MediaWiki setup. I have installed the Bootstrap Skin however it doesn't seem to be rendering anything out.

This is the path to my skins directory

```
/var/www/wiki/skins
```

Inside this I have the following

```
4 drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 2015-07-30 15:33 CologneBlue
4 drwxrwxrwx  7 root root 4096 2015-07-31 10:36 mediawiki-bootstrap
4 drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 2015-07-30 15:33 Modern
4 drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 2015-07-30 15:33 MonoBook
4 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 1288 2015-07-30 15:33 README
4 drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4096 2015-07-30 15:33 Vector
```

Inside the mediawiki-bootstap folder is the following

```
 4 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 2015-07-31 10:36 assets
 4 drwxrwxrwx 7 root root  4096 2015-07-31 10:37 bootstrap
 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   524 2015-07-31 10:36 Bootstrap.i18n.php
 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  2271 2015-07-31 10:36 bootstrap.php
12 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9274 2015-07-31 10:36 Bootstrap.renderer.php
 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3751 2015-07-31 10:36 Bootstrap.skin.php
 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   759 2015-07-31 10:36 DOMDebugPrinter.php
 4 drwxrwxrwx 8 root root  4096 2015-07-31 10:37 Font-Awesome
20 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18092 2015-07-31 10:36 LICENSE.txt
 8 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5131 2015-07-31 10:36 README.md
 4 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 2015-07-31 10:36 xsl
```

I have added the following to my LocalSettings.php file located in the wiki folder

```
require_once( "/var/www/wiki/skins/mediawiki-bootstrap/bootstrap.php");
$wgDefaultSkin = "bootstrap";
#$wgDefaultSkin = "modern";
```

When I change back to modern, the styling and CSS loads fine. When I move to bootstrap the page loads with no styling/formatting.

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestion why this is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the right place for this.  it's a programming site.

Comment: Did you read and follow https://github.com/mtyeh411/mediawiki-bootstrap#installation ?